# Find $G'(2) $, where $ G(x)= \int_{\pi/x}^{\pi x}\cos^{15}t\,dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives

Find $G'(2) $ where

$$ G(x)= \int_{\pi/x}^{\pi x}\cos^{15}t\,dt$$

Honestly, I don't know where to start. I need a full and detailed answer.

Comment: Do you know any of the standard results? Such as a theorem which is rather fundamental?

Comment: Are you sure that you are integrating wrt to $x$ aswell?

Answer (score 2):

Write $G(x)$ as

$$G(x)=F(\pi x)-F\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$$

where $$F(x)=\int \cos^{15} x$$

Then $$G'(x)=\pi F'(\pi x)+\frac{\pi}{x^2}F'\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$$
$$=\pi \cos^{15}(\pi x)+\frac{\pi}{x^2}\cos^{15}\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be the antiderivative of $\cos^{15}(x)$. Then, we have, $G(x)=F(\pi x)-F(\dfrac{\pi}{x})$

Then, $G'(x)=\pi F'(\pi x)+\dfrac{\pi}{x^2}F'(\dfrac{\pi}{x})$

Now substitute $x=2$ on both sides keeping in mind that $\cos^{15}(t)=F'(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),

$$G'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\pi x)\cdot \cos^{15}(\pi x) - \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\pi}{x})\cdot \cos^{15}(\frac{\pi}{x})$$
$$=\pi \cos^{15}(\pi x)+\frac{\pi}{x^2}\cos^{15}(\frac{\pi}{x})$$

You can calculate $G'(2)$.